# jQuery get each <img> element within specific column of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table is like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <img src="" />
           <span>blah</span>
       </td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

So in each row, first column contains an image. I need to register event on each of this image. So how can I select it?

I tried this:

```
td:eq(0):nth-child(0)
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('table tr td:first-child img').on('event', function (){
    // handle the event here
});
```

Comment: You should use the child selector `>` to make the selector more specific (and faster).

Answer (score 2):

something like this selector:

```
td:first-child > img
```

should work i guess...

Answer (score 2):

For `nth-child` selector, the index is 1 based.  I think something like this would work for you:

```
$("td:nth-child(1) > img")
```

or even simpler:

```
$("td:first-child > img")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you want to attach an event to the image, instead of iterating to each image, you could bind the event handler like this:

```
$("table").on("eventname", "td:first-child img", function(i){
 //your code
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/PYFhw/

Comment: You seem to be missing the point somewhat: he only needs to attach the event to images in the first column in the table, not all images within the table.

Comment: @AleksG saw the title "jQuery get **each** <img> element within specific column of the table" and this sentence "I need to register event on **each** of this image" and got confused :)..

Comment: I think your updated solution is still wrong: the OP needs images in the first column, not first row.  Plus, the selector is `:first-child`, not `:first`

Answer (score 0):

I think http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-how-to-select-all-first-tds-inside-all-tr-in-a-table contains several solutions:

`$('tr td:first-child')`

`$('tr').find('td:eq(0)')`

`$("tr td:nth-child(1)")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table > tr > td:first-child > img').bind('click', function() {
   // your code
});
```

I would give the table a unique id for more precision.

```
$('#table_id > tr > td:first-child > img').bind('click', function() {
   // your code
});
```

Replace *'click'* in the code above with wathever event you need to check.

Comment: That'll target all images within a `td`, OP wanted only images which are in the first column

Comment: @billyonecan oops, I missed this detail :)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first column image of the table as follows :

```
$('tr').find('td:eq(0)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$(function(){
$("table tr td:first-child").on("click","img",function(){
    console.log("hey");
});
});
```